# Filtering and selecting dataframe in pandas using outcome of .groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hello Python community,

I have a "little" Python/Pandas problem and would be very happy if someone could help me with it on short notice.
I have a dataframe with 2 IDs, date, hour of day and several metrics like in this example:

| index | ID_1 | ID_2 | date | hour | metric_1 | metric_2 | metric_3 | … | metric_k |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 0 | 11 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| 1 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 1 | 8 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| 2 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 2 | 7 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| 3 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 3 | 0 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| … | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 0 | 0 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| 22 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 22 | 17 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| 23 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 23 | 11 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| 24 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-10 | 0 | 9 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| 25 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-10 | 1 | 3 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| … | … | … | … | … | … | … | … | … | … |
| n | K510325 | 105983-20 | 2021-05-23 | 0 | 5 | any value | any value | … | any value |
| n+1 | K510325 | 105983-20 | 2021-05-23 | 1 | 1 | any value | any value | … | any value |

For each metric, one value is determined per device per day per hour. A device is made unique with 2 IDs because one ID is not unique. Now I want to know per device and per day at which hour e.g. metric_1 reaches the maximum value to see a distribution of hours with maximum values.

Using `df[['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'date', 'metric_1']].groupby(['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'date'], as_index=False).max()` I do get the maximum value of the day for a device displayed:

|  | ID_1 | ID_2 | date | metric_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| index |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-09 | 17 |
| 1 | A101321 | 25459379 | 2021-05-10 | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| m | K510325 | 105983-20 | 2021-05-23 | 5 |

but I can't see at what hour and all attempts to achieve this have failed miserably so far...
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you take your groupby, which seems to produce the results you want, instead use

```
df[['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'date', 'metric_1']].groupby(['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'date']).idxmax()
```

This gets the indices for those maximum values. Then subset in your original data frame for those specific indices using `df.loc[indicies, list_of_columns]`, if the result of the above code block is assigned to `indicies`.